# Scrolling QGraphicsView programmatically

Tags: python, qt

I've want to implement a scroll/pan-feature on a QGraphicsView in my (Py)Qt application. It's supposed to work like this: The user presses the middle mouse button, and the view scrolls as the user moves the mouse (this is quite a common feature).
I tried using the scroll() method inherited from QWidget. However, this somehow moves the view instead - scrollbars and all. See picture.
So, given that this is not the way I'm supposed to do this, how should I? Or is it the correct way, but I do something else wrong? The code I use:

```
   def __init__(self):
       ...

       self.ui.imageArea.mousePressEvent=self.evImagePress
       self.ui.imageArea.mouseMoveEvent=self.evMouseMove

       self.scrollOnMove=False
       self.scrollOrigin=[]

       ...

   def evImagePress(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.evImageLeftClick(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.scrollOnMove=not self.scrollOnMove
            if self.scrollOnMove:
                self.scrollOrigin=[event.x(), event.y()]
   ...

   def evMouseMove(self, event):
        if self.scrollOnMove:
            self.ui.imageArea.scroll(event.x()-self.scrollOrigin[0],
                                     event.y()-self.scrollOrigin[1])
```

It works as I expect, except for the whole move-the-widget business.

[Fails to scroll http://img55.imageshack.us/img55/3222/scrollfail.jpg](http://img55.imageshack.us/img55/3222/scrollfail.jpg)

Comment: What widget type is self.ui.imageArea?  Is it a QScrollArea, QGraphicsArea, or something else?

Comment: Oh, didn't mention it in the text, but in the title. It's a QGraphicsView.

Comment: So is the QScrollArea inside the QGraphicsScene that the view is displaying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done this myself but this is from the [`QGraphicsView`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qgraphicsview.html) documentation

> ... When the scene is larger
>   than the scroll bars' values, you can
>   choose to use translate() to navigate
>   the scene instead.

By using `scroll` you are moving the widget, [`translate`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qgraphicsview.html#translate) should achieve what you are looking for, moving the contents of the `QGraphicsScene` underneath the view

Comment: Well, the scene isn't larger than the allowed values of the scrollbars, so it shouldn't be a problem. But I tried translating too, but that just sort of made the image shudder back and forth. I think it got re-centered automatically?

Comment: I am looking at the docs, have you tried `setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag)` and is the value of `interactive` set to `true` ?

Comment: re translate, you need  
  view.setTransformationAnchor( QtGui.QGraphicsView.NoAnchor )  
else translate() is a noop ?!

Comment: Harald: Thanks for your suggestiong, I just tried that.  
It changed how the widget moved around, but it was still the widget that got moved.

Answer (score 4):

My addition to translate() method.
It works great unless you scale the scene. If you do this, you'll notice, that the image is not in sync with your mouse movements. That's when mapToScene() comes to help. You should map your points from mouse events to scene coordinates. Then the mapped difference goes to translate(), voila viola- your scene follows your mouse with a great precision.

For example:

```
QPointF tmp2 = mapToScene(event->pos());
QPointF tmp = tmp2.mapToScene(previous_point);
translate(tmp.x(),tmp.y());
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by denis is correct to get translate to work.  The comment by PF4Public is also valid: this can screw up scaling.  My workaround is different than P4FPublc's -- instead of mapToScene I preserve the anchor and restore it after a translation:

```
previousAnchor = view.transformationAnchor()
#have to set this for self.translate() to work.
view.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.NoAnchor)
view.translate(x_diff,y_diff)
#have to reset the anchor or scaling (zoom) stops working:
view.setTransformationAnchor(previousAnchor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the QGraphicsScene's area that will be displayed by the QGraphicsView with the method [QGraphicsView::setSceneRect()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop). So when you press the button and move the mouse, you can change the center of the displayed part of the scene and achieve your goal.